# Multiplication of two input table element values on html form row not working (Google Webapp)

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I am trying to create an order form as a table, where a user enters a quantity required for a product in a row and the corresponding value is calculated by multiplying the user entry by the price held in another element of the same row of the table.

The form is loaded as a WebApp via Google and uses an Apps Script to retrieve the table values from a Google Sheet. The form loads OK with the data as expected but I just can't get the calculation part to work.

If I click the "place Order" button at the bottom of the form, the numberUsed values are included as parameters in the URL so it looks as though the values are updating in those elements but I haven't been able to access them to do the calculation and display it in the element called "value".

I am a novice programmer so I am sure it is something basic I am doing wrong (or not doing). I have created a JSBin https://jsbin.com/siwerat/edit?html,js,console,output and I have tried several variations of code derived from other answers and videos over the last couple of weeks without success so any help will be much appreciated.

```js
//var numRows;
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  //new
  var elems = document.querySelectorAll('cart');
  var instances = M.FormSelect.init(elems);
  // end new

  document.getElementByname("cart").addEventListener("submit", getValues); //used to submit form - needs validation
  //document.getElementByName("numberUsed").addEventListener("oninput",getValues);//used to submit form - needs validation


});

function test(event) {
  "use strict";

  event.preventDefault();
  console.log("getValues function triggered");


}


function getValues() {

  event.preventDefault();
  var rows = document.querySelectorAll("package-row");
  rows.forEach(function(currentRow) {

    var numberUsed = Number(currentRow.querySelector('#numberUsed').value);
    var price = Number(currentRow.querySelector('#price').value);
    //var inPackage = Number(currentRow.querySelector('#inPackage').value);
    var inPackage = 1;
    var revenue = 1;

    document.querySelectorAll('numberUsed');

    if (numberUsed == "") {
      if (isNaN(inPackage) || isNaN(price)) {
        return;
      }
      revenue = price * inPackage;
    } else {
      if (isNaN(numberUsed) || isNaN(price)) {
        return;
      }
      revenue = price * numberUsed;
    }
    var value = revenue * 5;
    //currentRow.querySelector("#revenue").innerHTML = revenue;
    currentRow.querySelector("#value").innerHTML = value;
  });

}
```

Comment: Can you minimise your problem down? What is it you're trying to do, and what exactly isn't working? What is it doing instead? Questions on stackoverflow should address one problem at a time and should include a minimal reproducible example of what your problem is for others to follow. JS bin doesn't run Apps Script scriplets (the lines starting with `<?=`) and you haven't included your `.gs` code so this isn't followable at all. Please revisit your question and narrow down your problem as concisely as you can.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Rafa for the guidance.  After further reading/analysis I have got it working.  The Event bubbling video by Learn Google Spreadsheets: [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fYpGe5ngujk][1] and an article on EncodeDNA.com (Dynamically create HTML table and Button using Javascript) helped narrow down the issues I had to get a solution.